# Partially group records in access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a raw data table storing daily order snapshot and i am working on it to group consecutive order records with same information to return a query that only show the changes of each order no. and the date of change for further analysis.

The raw data is like below:

```
Order no.     Date      ETD     Destination<br/>
      01    5/1/2018  7/09/2018     City A<br/>
      01    5/2/2018  7/16/2018     City A<br/>
      01    5/3/2018  7/16/2018     City A<br/>
      01    5/4/2018  7/09/2018     City A<br/>
      01    5/5/2018  7/09/2018     City A<br/>
      01    5/6/2018  7/09/2018     City A<br/>
```

And i would like the result to be:

```
Order no.     Date      ETD     Destination<br/>
      01    5/1/2018  7/09/2018     City A<br/>
      01    5/2/2018  7/16/2018     City A<br/>
      01    5/4/2018  7/09/2018     City A<br/>
```

My current approach is to use VBA to loop through the sorted data set one by one to compare each record with previous one and extract it to another table if it is different.

Since there are too many records the performance is time costing and i would like to ask if there is any other better solution.

I've tried to use sub-query to link with previous day's data for comparison and it seems to be much more slower.

Thanks for all the supports.

Comment: Is 'lag' supported? if so you can use that

Comment: Maybe I am the only one, but I am more than a little confused as to what you're asking with this. Would you kindly post your VBA and/or SQL query that you've tried?

Comment: @Daniel Marcus Thanks but looks like lag function is not available in ms access

Comment: @Jiggles32 Hi Jiggles, what i am trying to do is to get all the records that are different from previous record in any of fields.

Comment: Without lag I think this will be tough to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are consecutive with no gaps -- as in your example data -- you an do:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.orderno = tprev.orderno and t.date = dateadd("d", 1, tprev.date)
where tprev.orderno is null or
      (tprev.etd <> t.etd or tprev.destination <> t.destination);
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry my example data was misleading, there actually are gaps in my real data. i have tried similar SQL by using sub query and Max() function, but since my real data contains 1 million records and 20 fields i found it very slow to use sub query.